# How to host a php site in windows server 2008

Tags: php, iis, hosting, windows-server-2008

I create and run a php site using xampp. Its working fine in my local system. i have a windows server 2008. I would like to host the site in server. I don't have any idea. Please help me to do this.

Comment: what else you tried..?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official guide on how to run PHP on Windows server 2008:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php